# Google drive api read permission V3

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Hello I am trying to write a code (c#) which will give public read permission to file, here is the code:

```
private static Permission MakeFilePublic(string fileId, DriveService driveService)
    {
        var request = driveService.Permissions.List(fileId);
        var res = driveService.Permissions.List(fileId).Execute(); 
        var hasReadPermission = res.Permissions.Any(p => p.Role == "reader");
        if (hasReadPermission==false)
        {
            var per = CreatePermission(driveService, fileId, "myemail@gmail.com", "anyone", "reader");
            return per;

        }
        return null;
    }

public static Permission CreatePermission(DriveService service, String fileId, String userEmailAddress, String type, String role)
{
    Permission newPermission = new Permission();
    newPermission.EmailAddress = userEmailAddress;
    newPermission.Type = type;
    newPermission.Role = role;
    try
    {
        var res =  service.Permissions.Create(newPermission, fileId).Execute();
        return res;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```

My problem is that I get an error

> The specified emailAddress is invalid or not applicable for the given permission type.

I tried to enter empty email, my email, nothing worked. 
anyone know how to solve it, and make the google document file share as public
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to repro the response from the *Try this API* section in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create).

I got a 200 OK response after *removing* the `emailAddress` parameter from the request. Double checked the file and it was shared publicly.

Comment: @user3728728 How was it? Were you able to successfully share the file after removing the `emailAddress` from your request?